# How to extract promise array into route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

this is the async method it returns routes

```
export const listOfMenus = async () => {
var listOfallMenus;
await axios.default({
    method: 'post',
    url: '/Access/GetAllMenusForRoutes',
}).then(data => {

    if (data.data.status == 'success') {
        debugger
         listOfallMenus = data.data.listOfallMenus;

        renderMenuArea = listOfallMenus.map((menu: any) => {
            return (<Route key={menu} exact path={'/' + menu + ''} component={menu} />)
        })
    }
});

return renderMenuArea ;}
```

but it gives promise array. when i print this.listOfMenus()

`2: Promise
__proto__: Promise
[[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved"
[[PromiseValue]]: Array(11)`

How can append into this renderArea into render area

```
renderArea = <Layout>
<Switch>
    <Route exact path='/' component={Workspace} />
    <Route path='/Settings' component={UserSetting} />
    {this.listOfMenus()} 
    <Route exact path='/users/Login' component={Login} />
    <Route path='/Users' component={Users} />
    <Route path='/Lead/:leadId' component={LeadDetails} />
    <Route path='/LeadContactDetails/:contactId' component={LeadContactDetails} />
    <Route component={NoMatch} />

</Switch>
```

;

All data are should append into renderArea. finally I expect like this

```
renderArea = <Layout>
<Switch>
    <Route exact path='/' component={Workspace} />
    <Route path='/Settings' component={UserSetting} />
    <Route path='/Stage' component={Stage} />
    <Route exact path='/Tag' component={Tag} />
    <Route exact path='/Cause' component={Cause} />
    <Route path='/Product' component={Product} />
    <Route exact path='/Source' component={Source} />
    <Route exact path='/Todo' component={Todo} />
    <Route exact path='/Pipeline' component={Pipeline} />
    <Route path='/Zone' component={Zone} />
    <Route path='/Todo' component={Todo} />
    <Route path='/ArchivedLeads' component={ArchivedLeads}/>*/}
    <Route exact path='/users/Login' component={Login} />
    <Route path='/Users' component={Users} />       
    <Route path='/Lead/:leadId' component={LeadDetails} />
    <Route path='/LeadContactDetails/:contactId' component={LeadContactDetails} />
    <Route component={NoMatch} />

    </Switch>
</Layout>;
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't return a promise array, it returns a promise of an array (or `undefined`, depending on `data.data.status`). You wait for the promise to resolve, then set state, which will trigger a render; in the render, you render those routes.

Presumably you call function that from `componentDidMount`, so:

```
componentDidMount() {
    listOfMenus()
    .then(routes => {
        if (routes) {
            this.setState({routes});
        }
    })
    .catch(error => {
        // Handle error
    });
}
```

...and in `render`:

```
renderArea = <Layout>
<Switch>
    <Route exact path='/' component={Workspace} />
    <Route path='/Settings' component={UserSetting} />
    {this.listOfMenus()} 
    <Route exact path='/users/Login' component={Login} />
    <Route path='/Users' component={Users} />
    <Route path='/Lead/:leadId' component={LeadDetails} />
    <Route path='/LeadContactDetails/:contactId' component={LeadContactDetails} />
    <Route component={NoMatch} />
    {this.state.routes}
</Switch>
```

(I assume there's a `</Layout>` somewhere.)

You'll also want

```
this.state = {routes: []};
```

in your constructor.

---

In `listOfMenus`, you're combining explicit promise use with `await`, which is unnecessary in most cases; just use one of the other. Since you're using an `async` function, using `await` is clearer (in my view). Also, rather than having the promise resolve with `undefined` when `data.data.status` isn't `"success"`, have it *reject* (by throwing an error). Then you don't need the `if (routes)` when consuming it. For example:

```
export const listOfMenus = async () => {
    const data = await axios.default({
        method: 'post',
        url: '/Access/GetAllMenusForRoutes',
    });

    if (data.data.status != 'success') {
        throw new Error(data.data.status);
    }

    return data.data.listOfallMenus.map((menu: any) => (
        <Route key={menu} exact path={'/' + menu + ''} component={menu} />
    );
}
```

then in `componentDidMount`:

```
componentDidMount() {
    listOfMenus()
    .then(routes => this.setState({routes}))
    .catch(error => {
        // Handle error
    });
}
```

Comment: I have not use state here

Comment: @ibjas - If the component itself is the one making the call, you have to. Otherwise, you have to do the call in the component's parent and then pass the menus to the component once you have them, as props.